# Forcing RGB (3 bands) in raster using ArcPy

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, arcgis-10.0, dem

I'd like to include conversion to a 3 band RGB raster in a script to prepare multiple DEMs for image processing. The input files are rasters extracted from a raster mosaic.

The manual option is to use the Export Data option in the TOC, but I have to repeat this for 15-25 different rasters so I'd like to automate it.

*Each input raster is a single band that I'd like to force RGB like the image below (maunal method).*

[image]

Comment: maybe this is what your looking for arcpy.RasterToOtherFormat_conversion()

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think 3-band RGB is an option

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got some help from an ESRI employee.  Apparently there isn't a Python method available to accomplish this, but you can export a Raster and force RGB [through ArcObjects](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/componenthelp/index.html#//001200000p9r000000) (IRasterLayerExport Interface).

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to use the Copy Raster tool.  It is in the Data Management Toolbox under Raster / Raster Dataset  or  arcpy.CopyRaster_management.   Be sure to set the colormap_to_RGB value.

Comment: This certainly looks like the right tool, but I can't seem to get a three band output.  I'm getting a 1 band with stretched symbology.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have time to test this but it should work. If you take the total number or pixels in your raster and multiple it three and use this number to create a numpy array. This array can be then reshaped into a 3 dimensional array. Now you have an empty array that represents your RGB raster. So if you now convert your original DEM till a numpy array you could loop over it and add the values to your newly created array and then save that as what every image type you want.

Answer (score 0):

Try the [Composite Bands (Data Management)](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00170000009p000000) tool:

> - This tool can also create a raster dataset containing subset of the original raster dataset bands. This is useful if you need to create a new raster dataset with a specific band combination and order.
> - The order that the bands are listed in the Multi-value Input control box will determine the order of the bands in the output raster dataset.

Comment: Thanks, but the original file is a single band raster, this looks like a tool for combining several single band rasters into a multi band composite rather than forcing a single band into a 3-band RGB.