# Forcing RGB in raster using QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, rgb

I have rasters in 1 band 64bits float that represent real data values and for which I can set min and max using the stretch to min and max option in QGIS.

I would like to convert these rasters to RGB 8 bits with a greyscale and with the min and max that I have set.

It is easy to do in ArcGIS as it can be seen at [Forcing RGB (3 bands) in raster using ArcPy](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/28438/is-there-a-way-to-programatically-force-rgb-3-bands-in-a-raster-with-arcpy)

I am looking for a way to do the same thing in QGIS. I do not need a script, I just need to be able to do the conversion.

Does anyone know a way to do it in QGIS?

---

I have found this plugin and tried to install it. I edited my first post but when I finished, it gave me a message saying the edit had to be reviewed and it has not been updated yet. I am having an error message when I try to execute the plugin related to the Python code

```
    An error has occured while executing Python code:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/user/.qgis//python/plugins\bccAddRColor\bccAddRColor.py", line 140, in DoWork
    cplArray, nod )
  File "C:/Users/user/.qgis//python/plugins\bccAddRColor\qml2gdal.py", line 599, in rasterOPal
    tif_ds.GetRasterBand(1).SetRasterColorTable( ct )
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'GetRasterBand'

Python version:
2.7.2 (default, Jun 12 2011, 15:08:59) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)]


QGIS version:
1.8.0-Lisboa Lisboa, 6416f38

Python path: ['C:\\Users\\user\\.qgis\\python\\plugins\\GeoCoding', 'C:\\Users\\user\\.qgis\\python\\plugins\\GeoCoding', 'C:/OSGeo4W/apps/qgis/./python', 'C:/Users/user/.qgis//python', 'C:/Users/user/.qgis//python/plugins', 'C:/OSGeo4W/apps/qgis/./python/plugins', 'C:\\Windows\\system32\\python27.zip', 'C:\\OSGeo4W\\apps\\Python27\\DLLs', 'C:\\OSGeo4W\\apps\\Python27\\lib', 'C:\\OSGeo4W\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\plat-win', 'C:\\OSGeo4W\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\lib-tk', 'C:\\OSGeo4W\\apps\\qgis\\bin', 'C:\\OSGeo4W\\apps\\Python27', 'C:\\OSGeo4W\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages', 'C:\\OSGeo4W\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\PIL', 'C:\\OSGeo4W\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\win32', 'C:\\OSGeo4W\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\win32\\lib', 'C:\\OSGeo4W\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\Pythonwin', 'C:\\OSGeo4W\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\wx-2.8-msw-unicode', 'C:\\Users\\user\\.qgis\\python\\plugins\\mmqgis/forms', '/usr/share/qgis/python', 'C:\\OSGeo4W\\apps\\qgis\\python\\plugins\\fTools\\tools',
```

I have tried to reinstall it and I checked the repository but there is no change. I documented the problem sending it to the user-list specified on the plugin's webpage and I am waiting for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by installing a plugin called "Convert 1-band raster to a paletted raster or RGB raster". It is not in the main QGIS repository, so download and installed it from

http://www.bc-consult.com/freebies.htm

First you will have to create a styled raster and save the QML file. The same folks have a handy plugin called "1-band raster colour table" that has many built-in styles including grayscale. Apply that, save the style as a QML file and use the plugin to convert to RGB.